# Seperating list 1 into two list 2 & 3 and summing up 2&3 give a result different from list 1 however it sould be the same

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, spacy

I am trying to extract sentences which contains the term "mais" in a list of sentences but the printing of the results (sentences which have it and sentences which does not have it) show less data than the real total. Normally the list of extracted and not extracted should correspond to the total sentences in the original file but in my case, it does not.

```
import spacy.attrs
from spacy.attrs import POS
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.lang.fr import French
from spacy.tokenizer import Tokenizer
from spacy.util import compile_prefix_regex, compile_infix_regex, compile_suffix_regex
from spacy.lemmatizer import Lemmatizer
from spacy.matcher import Matcher, PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_md") # 95.72 précision 

def extraction_mais(texte): 
    pattern1 = [{"LOWER": "mais"} ] 

    matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)  
    matcher.add("mais", None, pattern1) 

    sent_extract=[] #list of extracted sentences with last attribute IN THE lexique
    sent_not_extract=[] #list of extracted sentences with last attribute NOT IN THE lexique

    for sent in texte:
        #sent = sent.lower()
        doc=nlp(sent)
        matches= matcher(doc)
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            span = doc[start:end].lemma_.split()
            #print("found match:", span)
            if span[0] in sent:
                if sent not in sent_extract:
                    sent_extract.append(sent)
            else:
                    sent_not_extract.append(sent)
                
    print(len(sent_extract)) 
    print(len(sent_not_extract))
    return sent_extract 


splits = ['tout', 'tout_2'] 

#splits = ['Freins', 'motivations'] 


for s in splits:
    print('Fichier', s,  'en cours de traitement........')
    path = os.path.join('/Users/Corpus_6399/', s + '.tsv')
    with open(path, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as l_1:
        l_1 = [line.rstrip() for line in l_1]
        print("total phrases du fichier ", s, ":", len(l_1),  "\n")
        l_1 = extraction_mais(l_1)
```

Results

```
******************************************************************************************
******************************************************************************************
******************************************************************************************
Fichier tout en cours de traitement........
total phrases du fichier  tout : 3500 

3173
16
```

3173 + 16  does not equal to 3500.

When I try with small data it seems to work

```
l_1 = ['"""""""J\'aime beaucoup la saga des Mallory, il n\'y a que le 2ième """"""""tendre rebelle"""""""" que j\'ai un peu moins apprécié à cause de son héroîne, trop orgueilleuse, Anthony méritait mieux, mais bon..."""', 'Les chansons a part Rubbernecking ne sont pas fantastiques mais elles sont peu nombreuses.', '"""Son arrivée était fracassante, mais le choix de sa chanson n\'était vraiment pas intéressant, vu que c\'était une soirée consacrée aux divas, pourquoi ne pas prendre """"""""I\'m not giving you up"""""""", l\'une de ses plus belles ballades..."""', 'Le flow de Juelz passe trés bien, mais les lyrics ne varient pas tellement.', "Certes, chacun ses goûts, mais keane avait creusé le sillon d'une musique pop élégante à défaut d'être extrêmement novatrice, et ce nouvel album n'a vraiment rien en commun avec ses prédecesseurs... un conseil écoutez le avant de l'acheter, surtout si vous aviez aimé les 2 premiers.....", 'Bref à éviter comme littérature mais surtout comme documentation sur ce mal si grave..', '"""Or , depuis l\'excellentissime """"""""Dig Your Own Hole"""""""" les chemicals que j\'aime s\'estompent doucement mais surement .Bref , avec """"""""push the button"""""""" je me demande meme si se sont les memes..."""', "- Esther Nubiola est certes très jolie, mais elle baragouine (pas assez d'actrices francophones disponibles pour le rôle ?), donc on tend souvent l'oreille pour comprendre ce qu'elle a à dire en tant que Diane de M. et c'est un peu dérangeant ;", '"""""""Une rave qui arrive à point nommé, pour l\'été, j\'appelle vraiment pas ça de l\'électro à proprement parlé mais une dance réchauffée 40 fois qui s\'inscrit de toute façon dans le même rang que les Fuck Me I\'m Famous."""', 'Je me suis franchement ennuyé, mais pour être honnête je ne suis plus très fleur bleue, mais amateur de films plus vivant.', "Je n'ai rien contre les mangas, j'en lis quand j'en choisis, mais là on est loin des personnages de la série de départ...", '"""Alors oui, c\'est """"""""bien"""""""" ecrit, l\'auteur sait tout du moins au debut, nous tenir en haleine..mais passé les premieres surprises et la petite pointe de paranormal qui enrobe tout ca, reste un roman vide, qui laisse une impression de """"""""ouais bof"""""""" la derniere page tournée et qu\'on oublie tres vite."""', "Je lui attribue tout de même deux étoiles mais uniquement parce qu'il se lit très rapidement et tant mieux finalement, j'étais assez contente de passer à autre chose.", "Aucun approfondissement sur les techniques, aucune explication sur les noms de domaine, les réécritures d'url... Marie Prat évoque mais n'explique pas.", '""", des chansons qui se ressemblent toutes... allez j\'marrête là histoire de pas décourager les fans, après tout chacun ses gout mais bon..."""""""', 'La vérité est ailleurs...mais sûrement pas dans les crop circles.', '"""""""Non seulement ce livre accumule les clichés sans aucune honte (Elfe= belle, chevalier= courageux...), mais en plus ça pompe sur Tolkien, et ça pompe avec une maladresse en plus!"""', "J'ai quand même mi 2étoile car il a quand même une certaine qualité, mais elle n'est pas à la hauteur de la notoriété du groupe.", "et puis ca commence super bien, une histoire de meurtre sans que l'on connaisse vraiment l'assassiné et le meurtrier, chaque chapitre laisse la parole à une personne ou à une chose différente (c'est vraiment surprenant et amusant), une histoire d'amour non accomplie... mais sincèrement au bout de 100 pages j'ai vraiment commencé à decrocher car l'histoire piétine, il ne se passe pas grand chose, c'est très et beaucoup trop descriptif sur les détails de tous les jours sur la vie des différents personnages, sans que l'intrigue ne progresse...", "J'ai eu souvent envie d'arrêter la lecture de ce livre que j'ai trouvé bien écrit certes mais ennuyeux au possible, toute l'histoire tourne autour d'un naufrage et d'un enfant disparu.", "ce roman aurait dû être exceptionnel mais c'est finalement révélé décevant et ennuyeux.", '"""Un clin d\'oeil à sa maladie """"""""Single vision"""""""", même pas dérisoire... Bon le reste (ce qui reste...) tourne un peu mieux, mais ne décolle jamais."""', "Eminem a raison c'est naze, affligeant, ecoeurant, le Cd est tout juste bon à caler une table... mais y'a mieux quand-même.", "La suite du chef d'oeuvre de Don Bluth ne porte pas la signature du maître et pour cause:le dessin et l'animation sont de moins qualité que le premier opus mais surtout la richesse scénaristique a disparu au profit d'une histoire linéaire.", "Encore une fois la pensée unique Obispienne presente partout parmis les medias et les programmateurs a frappé faisant de ce Biolay un chanteur à la mode- tres loin du genie d'un Gainsbourg auquel je l'ai deja entendu comparer,mais plutot a sa place comme parrain de la star ac..(ce n'est pas un compliment :) )", '"""En 1981, j\'étais encore jeune mais j\'ai pas le souvenir que les """"""""live"""""""" était aussi approximatifs en qualité."""']

l_1 = [line.rstrip() for line in l_1]
print("total phrases du fichier ", s, ":", len(l_1),  "\n")
        
#print(l_1)
l_1 = extraction_mais(l_1)
```

result

```
total phrases du fichier  tout_2 : 26 

26
0
```

Comment: you need an `else` for this `if sent not in sent_extract:` in which you need to append it in list `sent_not_extract`

Comment: @AmitKumar I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: I want to have a list of sentence where the pattern mais is found and the other one where it is not. If I follow your logic  I append in sent_not _extract , sentence which have "mais" but are already present in sent_extract; I do not find the logic.

Answer (score 0):

actual issue with the below code is that:

- for each sent in text you are calling `nlp(sent)` and running the `matcher(doc)` which is correct.
- Now `matcher(doc)` will be either empty list(if "mais" is not present in the sent) or else it will contains the values if "mais" is present in the sent (if in the sentence "mais" is present at multiple locations the `matcher(doc)` will return multiple output for the same sentence), you are only getting the values in `sent_not_extracted` because you are converting the text to it's lemma form (i guess it will only check if "mais" in smaller case is present in the sent) and then checking if lemma from is present in the sent or not (which might not be the case always).
- for scenario where "mais" is not at all found in the sent via `matcher(doc)` your inner for loop doesn't run as the `matcher(doc)` returns empty list.

```
for sent in texte:
    #sent = sent.lower()
    doc=nlp(sent)
    matches= matcher(doc)
    for match_id, start, end in matches:
        span = doc[start:end].lemma_.split()
        #print("found match:", span)
        if span[0] in sent:
            if sent not in sent_extract:
                sent_extract.append(sent)
        else:
                sent_not_extract.append(sent)
```

now for the solution there is two ways to do this.

1. If you just want to check if "mais" in any form (not only lemma form)

```
for sent in texte:
    #sent = sent.lower()
    doc=nlp(sent)
    matches= matcher(doc)
    #if "mais" is found
    if mateches:
         sent_extract.append(sent) 
    # if match is not found for "mais"
    else:
        sent_not_extract.append(sent)
```

second approach: if you want to check only if the lemma form is present("mais" in small case) then.

```
for sent in texte:
    #sent = sent.lower()
    doc=nlp(sent)
    matches= matcher(doc)
    #if "mais" is found
    if mateches:
        present_flg=False
        for match_id, start, end in matches:
            span = doc[start:end].lemma_.split()
            if span[0] in sent:
                present_flg=True
                break
        if present_flg:
            sent_extract.append(sent)
        else:
            sent_not_extract.append(sent)
    # if match is not found for "mais"
    else:
        sent_not_extract.append(sent)
```

NOTE: my answer is based on my understanding, i didn't ran the above code to confirm the logic. Also let me know if i missed any thing.